# Get Selected Files directories with wxThumbnailCtrl?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

How can I get the directories of the selected items in a wxThumbCtrl in wxpython?

EDIT:

There is http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl.Thumb-class.html#GetFileName

However how can I even use this? Or does this even work?

I want to simply get where the selected image files are located

Answer (score 0):

All files shown in `wxThumbnailCtrl` at a given time are from *the same* directory (the only way of populating it is `tn.ShowDir()`, and you can't mix images from different folders). You can get this directory with `tn.GetShowDir()`.